# How to get the data in below format from html to ts file? I have mentioned the format below[Angular]

Tags: html, css, angular

How to get the data from html to ts file.
I want to get the data like the format below,
Needed Format:

```
{
      feedbackId: 1,
      applicantId:1,
      positionId:1,
      comments:'test',
      description:'test1',
      recommendation:1,
      status:1,
      resourceRating:[{skillId:1,ratingId:2},{skillId:2,ratingId:3},{skillId:3,ratingId:2},{skillId:4,ratingId:3
        },{skillId:5,ratingId:2},{skillId:6,ratingId:3},{skillId:7,ratingId:2},{skillId:8,ratingId:3}
      ]
    }
```

**This is the HTML Code**

```
        <form [formGroup]="feedbackForm" (ngSubmit)="submitData()">
            <div>
                <label class="form-control-label" for="">Rating Scale: </label>
                <div *ngFor='let rating of ratings'>{{rating.rating}}<span>.
                    </span>{{rating.ratingName}}</div>
            </div>
            <table class="res-tbl">
                <thead style="background-color: #f6f9fc;">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="table-head"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="skill-tr" *ngFor='let skill of skills; let i = index;'>
                            <td class="skill-td">
                                <b>{{skill.skillName}}<span>:</span></b>{{skill.description}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <mat-radio-group >
                                    <span class="radio-span">0</span><mat-radio-button class="radio-btn"   value="0"></mat-radio-button>
                                    <span class="radio-span">1</span><mat-radio-button  class="radio-btn"  value="1"></mat-radio-button>
                                    <span class="radio-span">2</span><mat-radio-button  class="radio-btn"  value="2"></mat-radio-button>
                                    <span class="radio-span">3</span><mat-radio-button  class="radio-btn"  value="3"></mat-radio-button>
                                    <span class="radio-span">4</span><mat-radio-button  class="radio-btn"  value="4"></mat-radio-button>
                                </mat-radio-group>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
```

**This is theTS Code**

```
export class FeedbackFormComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ratings = this.ratingService.getAllRatings();
        console.log(this.ratings);
        this.skills = this.skillService.getAllSkills();
        this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
          applicantId:[''],
          positionId:[''],
          comments:[''],
          recommendation:[],
          resourceRating: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.group({
            skillId:[''],
            ratingId:['']
          })])
        });    
  }
}
```

Could someone help me with this. I am new to Frontend and Angular.
This is the first form I am working in design and functionality.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to form the reactive form according to output json file then only you can get automatically get that format on click of submit

Comment: can you share some example?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call `getRawValue()` on the main FormGroup `this.feedbackForm` and this will get you all the form data in an object which you can use for you expected output.

Check this: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#getRawValue

Comment: it returns data in unreadable format. Not seems working